# Rationale for counterexamples in proof of existence of square roots of reals

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

In *Calculus Vol. 1*, Apostol proves that every real $a\ge 0$ has a nonegative square root $b=\sup S$ where $S=\{x>0|x^2\le a\}$ by first showing that $S$ is bounded above, applying the axiom of completeness and then disproving $b^2>a$ and $b^2<a$.  My question concerns the disproofs.

- It is shown that $b^2>a$ leads to $c=b-\dfrac{b^2-a}{2b}$ being an upper bound of $S$ less than $b$.  Recognizing $c$ as an improvement on $b$ in the approximation by Newton's  method to the equation $f(x):=x^2-a=0$, is it valid to interpret this part of the proof as: if the guess $b$ lies to the right of the sought root of $f$, the subsequent guess $c$ lies between $b$ and the root?  If so, can this be justified without resorting to unintuitive algebraic manipulations of $c$, as Apostol does?
- The disproof of $b^2<a$ involves choosing (a different) $c<(a-b^2)/(3b)$.  I have no idea where this comes from an would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: It's hell hard for textbook writers to guess which algebraic manipulations their readers will find intuitive. If you try to understand the proofs, your intuition might improve with time.

Comment: It doesn't matter where it comes from.  What matters is that it works.  Do you accept that it works?  But if you are idly curios as to why he chose that one... I can work you through it.

Comment: Vector -- I see what you mean.  By intuitive I suppose I mean in this case, having significance beyond the algebraic, like my analogy with graphs in the first case.  @fleablood -- Yes, please!  I accept it works, but there must be more to finding counter-examples than brute force trial and error.

Comment: mfl's explanation seems to be pretty good.  There are no high concepts issues involved.  It's nothing more or less than approximating $\sqrt {a}$ by taking rationals higher and or lower  $b^2 < a$  so find a $b^2 < (b + h)^2 < a$ and finding good candidates for h. It's a mallet.  Not a scalpel.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Note that $$c^2=\left(b-\dfrac{b^2-a}{2b}\right)^2=b^2-2b\dfrac{b^2-a}{2b}+\left(\dfrac{b^2-a}{2b}\right)^2=a+\left(\dfrac{b^2-a}{2b}\right)^2>a$$ since $b^2>a.$  Thus $c<b$ and $c>\sqrt a.$

Comment: mfl -- Thanks, but this is what Apostol does (though you wrote it out more clearly).  I was thinking more of high-level concepts, which are properly introduced later, but provide motivation for the formalization of low-level proofs.

Comment: Regarding high-level concepts, I agree with the 2nd comment of @fleablood: there are no high-level concepts involved here. Nonetheless, there is a very important concept involved, however low its level in this problem, namely: estimates. This is an example of the kind of simple estimate that you have to do all the time in analysis, and surprisingly often in many "softer" branches of mathematics. Even simple muscles need exercise.